# How to fix Rijindael decryption (php code to python3 migration) IV problem?

Tags: php, python-3.x, encryption, rijndael, cbc-mode

I'm migrating my existing code to Python3, unfortunately the decryption shows error that IV must be 16 bytes long.

I have tried decrypting the key with sha1 then tried to decrypt.

My php5.6 code is

```
<?php

    define('ENCR_ALGO', MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256);
    define('ENCR_MODE', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    define('KEY',"This is test key");



    function encryptData($plaintext){

        $iv=generateIv();
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(ENCR_ALGO, getKey(), $plaintext, ENCR_MODE, $iv);
        $ciphertext.=$iv;
        return trim(base64_encode($ciphertext));
    }
    function decryptData($ciphertext){

        $iv=getIvFromCiphertext($ciphertext);
        $ciphertext=getActualCiphertext($ciphertext);
        $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(ENCR_ALGO, getKey(), $ciphertext, ENCR_MODE, $iv);
        return trim($plaintext);
    }

    function getIvFromCiphertext($encryptedData){
        $encryptedData  =   base64_decode($encryptedData);
        $cipherTextSize =   strlen($encryptedData);
        $ivStartIndex   =   $cipherTextSize-ivSize();
        return substr($encryptedData, $ivStartIndex , ivSize());
        }

    function getActualCiphertext($encryptedData){
        $encryptedData  =   base64_decode($encryptedData);
        $cipherTextSize =   strlen($encryptedData);

        return substr($encryptedData, 0,$cipherTextSize-ivSize());
        }

    function ivSize(){
        return mcrypt_get_iv_size(ENCR_ALGO, ENCR_MODE);
        }

    function keySize(){
        return mcrypt_get_key_size(ENCR_ALGO, ENCR_MODE);
        }

    function generateIv(){
        return mcrypt_create_iv(keySize(), MCRYPT_RAND );
    }

    function getKey(){
        return substr(sha1(KEY), 0, keySize());
    }

    echo "<br/>";
    echo encryptData("my pass");
    echo decryptData("vuv6kZgweA2YqSU4vMOuYStrbwZayDYaL7UQ+JajFCVc2p4HW1o68OmIm2l3Rbi/IaCWtKD5m6an7LqnvwRYVA==");
?>
```

In my python3 file, it's like

```
from hashlib import sha1
import base64
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


def actual_text(txt):
    data = base64.b64decode(txt)
    return data[:32], data[32:64]


passs = "vuv6kZgweA2YqSU4vMOuYStrbwZayDYaL7UQ+JajFCVc2p4HW1o68OmIm2l3Rbi/IaCWtKD5m6an7LqnvwRYVA=="

key = "This is test key"
text, iv = actual_text(passs)


class Encryptor:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def pad(self, s):
        return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

    def encrypt(self, message, key, key_size=256):
        message = self.pad(message)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)


    def decrypt(self, ciphertext, key, iv):
        # iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
        return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")


def make_sha1(s, encoding='utf-8'):
    return sha1(s.encode(encoding)).hexdigest()


make_sha1(key, encoding='utf-8')

key2 = make_sha1(key, encoding='utf-8')[:32]
print(iv)
enc = Encryptor(key2)
enc.decrypt(text,key2,iv)
```

The error is showing ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long

I've expected result is "my pass"

Comment: You cannot convert your code into AES. RIJNDAEL is not AES. It was a candidate for the AES competition and the winner. When AES has standardized it has differences from  RIJNDAEL. RIJNDAEL can have 128+32*k-bit block sizes whereas AES has only 128-bit. MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 has 256-bit block size, therefore, it is incompatible for AES.

Comment: LOL, the get key first performs a hash over a 16 character password (called KEY) which is then turned into the *hexadecimal* encoding of a SHA-1 hash (20 bytes, or 40 characters), which is then cut short to 32 characters, that get interpreted as bytes. You cannot make stuff like that up.

Comment: Note that I've voted to close the question as the IV and key handling is completely different in PHP and Python.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes what is your flag on close? unclear?

Comment: Too broad generally when I close this kind of questions. The question is clear: "please convert this code for me". At least, that's how I interpret it if there is not even an indication of stepping through the code and fixing it one conversion / value at a time. I can actually check the votes that have already been given by expanding existing votes, but I'm not sure if that is tied to one of the reputation based priv's.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for the comment I'm looking into it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes SHA-1 Keys is 40 charecters then cut into 32 Charecter. I've done this, for easier i have pasted that key as key2 , but i thought its related to iv.

Comment: No, SHA-1 doesn't have a key nor does it generate one. A SHA-1 value consists of 20 bytes, not 40 (hex) characters. You can use the "raw" bytes for a key if you use SHA-1 for *key derivation* but not the hexadecimal characters. However, you should really use a Password Based Key Derivation Function for that, like PBKDF2 or Argon2.